# jQuery click to run a function, click again to run another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a small piece of jQuery - when it's clicked it runs a function and when clicked again it runs another.

I have tried the following but this doesn't even run the first.

```
$('body').on('click', '.card--small', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('card--expanded');
    if (topCheck() == 'chrome') {
        $('.card--expanded .card--small__container').css({
            'top': '51px'
        });
    }
}, function() {
    console.log('clicked again');
    $(this).removeClass('card--expanded');
    if (topCheck() == 'chrome') {
        $('.card--expanded .card--small__container').css({
            'top': '0'
        });
    }
});

function topCheck() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) {
        if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
            console.log('Chrome');
        } else {
            return 'safari';
            console.log('Safari');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens on the third and fourth click? Is function2 being called on those clicks as well or do you want it to alternate? (at the time of comment I see there is one answer with an upvote and it doesn't alternate, I would suspect you want it to alternate)

Comment: A toggle of some sort is the best option here, pending you didn't want to run each function only once. A variable check or class name  could be your condition inside 1 function. Then just toggle the var or class during the execution.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `card--expanded` class as a flag to determine which click you need and design your function accordingly.

```
$('body').on('click', '.card--small', function (e) {
    var self = $(this),
        isExpanded = self.hasClass('card--expanded'),
        isChrome = topCheck() === 'chrome'; // will always be false as topCheck never returns 'chrome' (it returns either 'safari' or undefined).
    self.toggleClass('card--expanded', !isExpanded);
    if (!isExpanded) {
        console.log('clicked');
        if (isChrome) { // will never execute as isChrome will always be false
            $('.card--expanded .card--small__container').css({
                'top': '51px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        console.log('clicked again');
        if (isChrome) { // will never execute as isChrome will always be false
            $('.card--expanded .card--small__container').css({
                'top': '0'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The point is to use some external condition as a flag to keep track of the click state. This could be a global variable, or a local variable above your handler in the scope chain (or a CSS class, or a HTML5 data attribute, etc.). There are a number of ways to do this. Using a CSS class seems like a natural fit in your case.

Also, the `topCheck` function would be better written if there were a chance it could return `'chrome'`:

```
function topCheck() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf('safari') > -1) {
        if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
            return 'chrome';
            console.log('Chrome');
        } else {
            return 'safari';
            console.log('Safari');
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
function topCheck() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        browser = 'unknown';
    if (ua.indexOf('safari') > -1) {
        if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
            browser = 'chrome';
            console.log('Chrome');
        } else {
            browser = 'safari';
            console.log('Safari');
        }
    }
    return browser;
}
```

Personally, I dislike multiple return statements per function so I would use the second form.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.card--small').click( function(){
   // run function 1
   function_1();
   $(this).unbind('click').click( function(){
      // run function 2
      function_2();
   });
});
```

Inside function 2 you would have to rebind $('.card--small') to run function 1 on click, if you want to run function 1 again.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach without jQuery. Just keep some kind of state around to determine what to do.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div {
        background-color: #ff0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      var state = 0;

      function runIt() {
        if (state > 0) {
          doSomethingDifferent();
          state = 0;
          return;
        }
        doSomething();
        state = 1;
      }

      function doSomething() {
        alert("something");
      }

      function doSomethingDifferent() {
        alert("something different");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div onClick="runIt()">Click me</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Another approach would be to rebind the click event to another function.

Answer (score 0):

In your function topCheck nothing is returned when you detect Chrome. You only log it. Your click event calls the function topCheck but does not get anything back from the function when Chrome is detected. So your if statement probably gets an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question on how to toggle function called on click, your code should look something like this:

```
function click1() {
  // ...
  $(this).off('click', click1).on('click', click2)
}

function click2() {
  // ...
  $(this).off('click', click2).on('click', click1)
}

$('#link').on('click', click1)
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/seririjuqa/1/edit?html,js,output)

But from your code snippet it seems that it would be simpler to implement toggling in single function:

```
$('body').on('click', '.card--small', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('card--expanded') {
        $(this).addClass('card--expanded');
        if (topCheck() == 'chrome') {
            $('.card--expanded .card--small__container').css({
                'top': '51px'
            });
        }
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('card--expanded');
        if (topCheck() == 'chrome') {
            $('.card--expanded .card--small__container').css({
                'top': '0'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

css

```
.card--small__container {
    top:0px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
```

js

```
$("body")
.on("click", ".card--small", function () {    
    if (topCheck() == "Chrome" 
       && !$(this).data("clicked") 
       && !$(this).hasClass("card--expanded")) {
        $(this).data("clicked", true)
            .addClass("card--expanded")
            .css("top", "51px");
    } else if ( !! $(this).data("clicked") 
              && $(this).hasClass("card--expanded")) {
        $(".card--small")
        .css("top", "0")
        .removeClass("card--expanded");
    }
});

function topCheck() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return ua.indexOf("chrome") !== -1 ? "Chrome" : "Safari"
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o4ebav8t/